# C++ Unhandled exception when reading file

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

Trying to write .ply parser to use .ply models in OpenGL.

Trying to begin to read the .ply file and write all the lines of it out. 
My program does this but when it print out the last line i get Unhandled exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x62aad540 (msvcr100d.dll) in PLY parser.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    char buffer[10000];
    FILE * myFile;
    myFile = fopen("walkman.ply", "r");
    if(myFile != NULL)
    {
        while (!feof(myFile))
        {

               cout<<fgets(buffer, 10000, myFile);

        }
        fclose(myFile);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"file not found"<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This may be foolish error in my code, but it would be great if someone can spot the error causing this.

Comment: But you are not using `<fstream>` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we get into what the bug is, you should know that the "Unhandled exception ... Access violation reading location 0x00000000" message you get is *not* caused by a C++ exception; it's the Windows equivalent of "Segmentation fault".  Your code tried to dereference the NULL pointer.

Now, you have made one of the classic mistakes in working with `FILE` objects.  `feof(fp)` does not become true when you reach the end of the file.  It only becomes true after you have *attempted to read **past** the end of the file* at least once.  Thus, your read loop will iterate until *after* `fgets` attempts to read past the end of the file. And when `fgets` attempts to read past the end of the file, it *fails*, and returns a NULL pointer, which you blindly passed to `cout`.  Kaboom.

(By the way, this is also how `istream::eof()` works.)

The correct way to write this loop is

```
while (fgets(buffer, 10000, myFile))
    cout << buffer;
```

(Or, even better, one of these:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 10000, myFile))
    fputs(buffer, stdout));

while(myFile.get(buffer, 10000))
    cout << buffer;
```

it being a little weird to mix `stdio.h` FILEs and `iostream`s as you are doing.)

Answer (score 4):

`feof()` tells you that you've tried to read past the end of file, not that you've reached the end of file. `fgets()` returns NULL when you're at the end of file and there's no more data to read. That's where the exception is coming from. At the end of file, `feof()` will return false and `fgets()` will return `NULL`, which will cause the exception when your program tries to execute `cout << NULL;`.

This is the idiomatic way to write it in C style:

```
char buffer[10000];
FILE* myFile = fopen("walkman.ply", "r");
if (myFile != NULL) {
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), myFiles) {
        fputs(buffer, stdout);
    }
    fclose(myFile);
}
```

or in C++ style:

```
std::string buffer;
std::ifstream myFile("walkman.ply");
if (myFile.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(myFile, buffer)) {
        std::cout << buffer << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: `fgets` doesn't trim the terminating newline character, so you have to pair it with `fputs`, not `puts`.

Comment: @Zack: Thanks. It's been ages since I've written production C code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: my prognosis was wrong but still read the following if you were meant to use streams.

Also please consider using streams (in ) and vectors, these methods are a lot less error prone and fit in with the C++ style and ethos.

```
std::ifstream in("walkman.ply", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> v(istream_iterator<char>(in),
                    istream_iterator<char>( ));
```

or if that is supposed to a string value.

```
std::ifstream in("walkman.ply");
std::string str(istream_iterator<char>(in),
                istream_iterator<char>( ));
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Comment: This may happen, but it would give a different address for the access violation. Now it refers to 0x0000000, which means that somewhere the program is dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia to be blunt I consider this a C problem, not C++ if the error persists with the stream implementation I have given above then please let me know.

Comment: I'm not saying your solution is wrong, but that your diagnosis is incorrect.

Comment: Downvoted because "the char[] is not going to be null terminating" is not true: `fgets` guarantees that if it succeeds, it returns a nul-terminated string.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Sorry I came across harshly before. You are correct, Ferruccio has given a good technical answer, I personally would still use streams and from the tagging and wording of the question I think the OP meant to use streams but hasn't for some reason.

Comment: Also, if you want "C++ style and ethos", `ifstream("walkman.ply") >> cout.rdbuf()` is IIUC the optimal way to do this operation.

Comment: @Zack it depends where the goals was to print the file or not, if it was then yes that is a good way of doing, I assumed the buffer would eventually (even if not in the example) be used for something.